# How to generate unsigned apk with entry point index.js React native

Tags: react-native, apk, unsigned

Hi Currently I have watched upgraded react native version generates project with files index.js and App.js.Where earlier version contains files named index.android.js/index.ios.js.So While generating apk for device.

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

//It won't work as new version doesn't contain index.android.js.it's shows an error message can't find entry point index.android.js inside index.android.bundle.

//So what i have done,i have changed index.android.js to index.js as shown below.

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

//But after running command ./gradlew assembleDebug.The generated apk shows error application is not registered.

Note: App is running fine in emulator.Creating Apk for device creates these.

//I have tried one thing also Created a file named index.android.js and moved content of index.js to index.android.js to make it as entry point.So all goes fine in this case.But while i run it on device only stucks inside a red screen.but no error.

So my question is how to generate unsigned apk keeping index.js as entry point.Please help i have wasted a lot of time regarding this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you find any solution?